# How to calculate the column or row to add to a non-square matrix so that it is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say you have a 4x3 matrix. You wanted to either add a column, or remove a column to that it is now invertible. How would you calculate that new column or determine which row to remove so that the matrix is now invertible?

Comment: A matrix is invertible if its columns are linearly independent. Assume we have an nx(n-1) matrix: to make it square we either must add a column or remove a row. If it’s possible to add a column to the matrix and still satisfy the “columns are linearly independent” condition, then the resulting matrix is invertible. If it’s not possible (the current columns themselves aren’t linearly independent), then you should try to remove a row so that they are, but this isn’t always possible either.

Comment: Just to give a simple example: if your $4\times3$ matrix is the zero matrix, good luck adding a column or deleting a row to make it invertible.

Comment: If you add a column, the matrix becomes square and it is invertible if and only if $\det(A)\neq 0$.

Comment: To determine if your existing columns are independent, do column operations to clear out the entries above the diagonal. If doing so completely zeros out one of the columns, the original columns were not independent. If it does not zero out a column, then they were independent.

Comment: @Tom If the columns are not linearly independent then removing a row will not help since the same linear dependence will continue to hold.

Comment: @ronno Good point - didn't think that through, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do column operations to get the matrix to column echelon form. If there's exactly one zero row, then either remove that row or add that unit vector as a column. Otherwise the matrix has rank $\le 2$ and you're out of luck.